# Edit CSS backgrounds with jQuery w/button

Tags: jquery, css, edit

How can I edit some css with jquery. I want to set a background and edit it based on some buttons. I don't have a snippet; I just need an example to work with. 
Also, I want to do this in a css of a special link, as my javascript is in a different file.
I'm making a game and now I want to make the background change as a button is pressed. I am trying to edit the background-image attribute here.

```
body {
background-image = url("someurl.png");
repeat = no-repeat;
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Edit some CSS . You mean to say add css using JQuery?

Comment: you mind googling this term https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=How+can+I+edit+some+css+with+jquery.&oq=How+can+I+edit+some+css+with+jquery.&aqs=chrome..69i57j5j69i60j0l3.2720j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I am trying to say that if I could edit a css with a specific src....

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

`$('.button').click(function(){
   $('.element').css({'background-color':'red'});
});`

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';">Green</button>
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply css directly with .css() option.

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Or add and remove css class with:

https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of example in the net, and not difficult to find either

that said, here is an example from jQuery's docs:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>css demo</title>
  <style>
  div {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<span id="result">&nbsp;</span>
<div style="background-color:blue;"></div>
<div style="background-color:rgb(15,99,30);"></div>
<div style="background-color:#123456;"></div>
<div style="background-color:#f11;"></div>

<script>
$( "div" ).click(function() {
  var color = $( this ).css( "background-color" );
  $( "#result" ).html( "That div is <span style='color:" +
    color + ";'>" + color + "</span>." );
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

the full examples are http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

here is some snap of code may be this work well

```
$("#myParagraph").css({"backgroundColor":"black","color":"white");
```

check the [following link](http://jsfiddle.net/YPYz8/)